# KeypressEvent not working, How to correct it?

Tags: pyqt4, keypress

I am trying to get keypressevent work with the following code

```
import sys,
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print 'a'

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(371, 345)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(401, 600))
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icons/icon.png'))
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        mysize = MainWindow.geometry()
        hpos = ( screen.width() - mysize.width() ) / 2
        vpos = ( screen.height() - mysize.height() ) / 2
        MainWindow.move(hpos, vpos)
        #some GUI
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        cd=MainWindow.centralWidget()
        cd.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        cd.setFocus()
        self.actionHardware = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionHardware.setObjectName(("actionHardware"))
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)


        #COnnect odes


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        #sime button text codes

if __name__=="__main__" :
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code was partially generated using QTDesigner. I noticed that replacing Mainwindow.show() by ui.show() enables keypressevent but at the cost of not showing any buttons i create in the Mainwindow central widget

Comment: Your code works for me as long as a I change the line `MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)` to `MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self)`.

Comment: that'll cause all buttons i added in self.centralwidget to be hidden

Comment: Your `Ui_MainWindow` doesn't have a centralwidget attribute, so your code as written gives an `AttributeError`.  I'm thinking that it would help to refactor your code so that the MainWindow setup code is outside your `Ui_MainWindow` class.  `Ui_MainWindow` is the child widget of `MainWindow`.  It doesn't really conform to object oriented best practices for MainWindow's setup code to be there.  The way you have written it will still work, but I wonder if that isn't the source of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in the way you are re-using the code output by Designer. You defined Ui_MainWindow.keyPressEvent, and created an instance "ui" of the class. However: "ui" is never directly incorporated into the GUI anywhere (ui.setupUi adds other widgets, but not itself, to MainWindow) and thus events are never delivered to ui.

My approach would look more like this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):  ## note this does not need to inherit QWidget
    ...                       ## and ideally, this code should not be changed
    ...                       ## after designer generates it
    ...

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
        print "key press"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Window()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```